# android failed to make .apk on using ant debug

Tags: java, android, debugging, command-line, ant

i created one android project on command line using android tool. After adding aidl file, while compiling using the command (ant debug projectname), its giving the arro "BUILD FAILED"

Target "MyIpc" does not exist in the project "MyIpc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be issuing the command `ant debug` and nothing else. `ant debug projectname` is incorrect.